# Safari page not allowed to display insecure content

Tags: html, http, https, safari

Strange behaviour even though all url's in source code are "HTTPS" not "HTTP".

Really not sure where is calling the insecure content. (This error is both on Safari and Chrome)

Any opinions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated as i've looked through so many tutorials, i've updated my .htaccess file and got absolutely nowhere.

[blocked] The page at https://sam.dougbros.co.uk/ was not allowed to display insecure content from http://sam.dougbros.co.uk/Content/Font/OstrichSans-Medium.ttf. error message for https://sam.dougbros.co.uk project.

Thanks,

Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

During the page loading you are trying to load fonts over http `(https://sam.dougbros.co.uk/Content/Font/OstrichSans-Medium.ttf)` 
so request is being blocked